# Windows client connecting to UCS / Samba server - The join operation was not successful

Tags: linux, samba, active-directory

Using Univention Corporate Server `UCS`,
I have the following Linux distribution:

```
root@ucs:~# cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Univention
DISTRIB_RELEASE="4.2-2 errata159"
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Lesum

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Univention Corporate Server 4.2-2 errata159 (Lesum)"
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

and the following Samba version:

```
root@ucs:~# samba -V
Version 4.6.1-Debian
```

On this Linux machine I have configured the package:

```
Active Directory-compatible Domain Controller
```

I configured one user there: `myuser` which is under the group: `Domain Users`.

My problem is, when trying to connect to the local domain defined there: `mydomain.intranet`

I get the error:

```
The join operation was not successful. This could be because an existing computer account having name "MYUSER-PC" was previously created using a different set of credentials. Use a different computer name, or contact your administrator to remove any stale conflicting account. The error was:

Access is denied
```

as you can see on the following image:

[image]

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the offending computer from active directory and try again.

Comment: what's the offending computer? I think there is not any offending computer

Comment: So there are no computers on active directory called DELL-INSPIRON or MYUSER-PC?

Comment: no, that was not the problem. The solution was use the user: Administrator to add the computer to the domain. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to join your domain with your `myuser` user? This won't work as your user doesn't have the proper rights to add machines to your domain. Have you tried it with the user `Administrator` as shown here?

[image: this image]

As Raman already mentioned, you also want to make sure that there isn't already a machine with the name `DELL-INSIPRON` existent in your domain, but I assume that this won't be the case.